# Ubuntu black screen on startup

Tags: boot, 20.04, display, monitor, recovery-mode

I have a Lenovo T460 running Ubuntu 20.04. Recently I unplugged it from an external monitor and then restarted it. Since then it has stopped working correctly. Now when I turn it on, I see the Lenovo startup screen and then a black screen. I have to hold down the power button to turn off the computer.

On the next startup, I see the Lenovo startup screen and then the GRUB menu. Here is what happens when I choose the different options.

**Ubuntu**: black screen

**Advanced options for Ubuntu:**

**Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-50-generic:**
Loading Linux 5.8.0-50-generic...
Loading initial ramdisk... (never proceeds any farther)

**Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-50-generic (recovery mode):** Takes me to the recovery menu
resume: a cursor blinks in the top left corner forever (black screen on next startup)
clean: doesn't help
dpkg: doesn't help

failsafeX: [image: failsafeX error output]

fsck: [image: fsck error output] (then black screen after restart)

**Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-49-generic:**
Loading Linux 5.8.0-49-generic...
Loading initial ramdisk... (never proceeds any farther)

**Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-49-generic (recovery mode):** Takes me to the recovery menu
resume: success! The Ubuntu login screen. But external monitor doesn't work. After restart, the next time I see the Lenovo logo and then a black screen.
clean: doesn't help
dpkg: doesn't help
failsafeX: same as above
fsck: same as above

I have tried the [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), but that didn't help.

An external monitor doesn't work under any scenario. Sometimes after a hard restart, I see the Lenovo logo and then a black screen, and sometimes I see the Lenovo logo and then the GRUB menu. I haven't worked out any pattern.

I would really appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Is this a new install of Ubuntu or an existing one? If it's an existing one did you make any changes to your system before the problem happened?

Comment: @applemonkey496 This is an existing installation. I didn't make any changes. The problem started when I unplugged it from an external monitor and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a T460p which has exactly the same problem.  My work around for the last six months has been to boot into the 5.4 kernel.  Not a solution, I know, but I haven't been able to find an alternative.